# How do I get images to be overlaid on another custom shaped image like an iphone case?

Tags: html, css, image, overlay, render

Here's an example - they both have an iphone case image with another image on top of it:

Any idea how to automate something like this with several images?

http://society6.com/product/The-ocean-the-sea-the-wave_Phone-Skin?model=iphone5#3=125

http://society6.com/product/Chromatic-Skull_Phone-Skin?model=iphone5#3=125

Comment: You could try combining image clip with an svg shape

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you could TRY is using CSS like this::

```
img {
   position: relative;
   left: 0px;
   right: 0px;
   top: 0px;
   bottom: 0px;
}
```

Hope this helps you! If not you could always use Photoshop ;)